# Is there a reason to use &= rather than just = on a boolean?

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

I ran across some code today that was checking a number of error conditions. A single boolean was used all the way through, but instead of reassigning it every time with an `=`, it was reassigned with an `&=` resulting in a bit wise ANDing of the the previous value of the boolean and the new value. The code looked something like this:

```
bool result = FirstCheck();
Assert(result);
result &= SecondCheck();
Assert(result);
...
```

Now I'm curious why someone would do this? This is logically equivalent to just reassigning the value of the boolean as shown by the possible branches below:

1. FirstCheck fails (returns false) and program fails on assert and never makes it to SecondCheck
2. FirstCheck passes (returns true) and the program makes it to SecondCheck. If SecondCheck returns true, then result is true because true&true = true. If SecondCheck returns false, then result is false becasue true&false = false.

Since there is no logical difference, is there some other reason `&=` might be preferable? Or is it more likely that is is a relic of some old code that just never got changed?

EDIT:
To clarify, the Assert is always active code. I actually stumbled across this code while investigating a bug because the assert was failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that on the beginning it was:

```
bool result = FirstCheck();
result &= SecondCheck();
Assert(result);
```

so the code was checking that both results were positive, but then somebody added the Assert() after the firstCheck().

Or the person might be from C++ background and thought that bitwise operators are faster than logical ones.

Comment: Are there cases where bitwise operators are faster than logical ones?

Comment: This *doesn't* perform a bitwise AND.  The `&` operator, when called on booleans in C#, just does a non-short circuiting AND.  So it will never be faster, it could be slower.  It should only done if it's important that the side effects of `SecondCheck` be performed regardless of the value of `result`.  Either that, or it's just a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the reason is that you use a single bool to accumulate the return codes for multiple functions.

Without the &= you overwrite the return code with the latest function on every call, therefore you only ever test whether the last function was successful.  With &= if a single function returns false then the return code remains false from that point onwards, so you know that at least one function failed.

It saves writing code like this

```
bFirstCheck == fn1();
bSecondCheck == fn2();
bThirdCheck == fn3();

if (bFirstCheck && bSecondCheck && bThirdCheck) {
}
```

When you can write code like:

```
bCheck = fn1();
bCheck &= fn2();
bCheck &= fn3();

if (true == bCheck) {
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to compare a boolean to `true`.  It's a noop.  Just write `if(bCheck)`.

Comment: Thanks for the great response, however, this doesn't really answer my specific question, because the Asserts in between assignments negate any of the benefits you mentioned in your example

Comment: Assert() only applies to debug builds and is used here as a convenience to alert you to which function failed, it will compile down to a NO-OP in release builds.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming the assertions are enabled. If this is using [`Debug.Assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx), the method will only actually be called if the `DEBUG` conditional compilation symbol is defined.

Assuming `result` is used later on (beyond the assertion) then there's a difference when `FirstCheck()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, Assert might not always be active code.  Then let's assume that first and third check return true and second check returns false.  Thus if you had

```
x = FirstCheck()
x = SecondCheck()
x = ThirdCheck()
```

then x would equal true.

But, if you did

```
x &= FirstCheck()
x &= SecondCheck()
x &= ThirdCheck()
```

x would equal false